# NetBeans + Microsoft SQL Server 2012 jbdc drivers

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, swing, netbeans

I am trying to resolve problem: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jbdc.SQLServerDriver"

Actually what is my problem..whether is it a class path error or program error or by missing of library files.

//below is my code

```
    package projektsql;

/**
 *C:\ProgramFiles\MicrosoftJDBCDriver4.0forSQLServer\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4
 * @author m4rtin77
 * intergratedSecurity=true;
 */
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ProjektSQL {
    Connection conn = null;
    public static Connection ConnectDB(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jbdc.SQLServerDriver");
            String connstring = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=JavaSQLProjekt;intergratedSecurity=true;";



            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connstring);
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Polaczono:");       


            return conn;


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }  
    }
}
```

And one method in Jframe:

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        conn = ProjektSQL.ConnectDB();
```

I really dont know what is gonna out there.

Comment: Have you added the library/dependency to your class path?

Comment: You've got a typo: com.microsoft.sqlserver. **jbdc** .SQLServerDriver. It must be `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`.

Comment: Yes I added. Ok i gonna try change:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:0a502bda-6e66-4c23-b74d-ae77222b8316
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)

Comment: There is another typo at `intergratedSecurity=true`. It should be spelt 'integrated'.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add SQL Driver Jar file to your project Library and I think you misspelled **jdbc** dude